# For Loop, Int Max

Tags: java, for-loop, count, max

I am a beginner in Java, can somebody please explain me what this code means and how it comes to the answer of 15. I understand for loop but not what it is doing with `int max`.

```
int count;
int max = 3;
for (count = 1; count < 7; count++) {
    max = max + 2;
}
System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: `max` has an initial value of `3`, and is incremented by `2` six times. `3 + (2 * 6) = 15`

Answer (score 0):

Max is initiated at 3. The code is adding 2 to max each time it goes through the for loop, a total `6` times `(7 - 1). 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 15`.

Answer (score 0):

So for loops are counting loops. The can do something a certain number of times. In this case count starts at 1 and goes until 6 because last run that count is less than 7. So in effect the amount of max that starts at 3 and then has 2 added to it 6 times, the number of times the for loop runs. Hope this helps! I just finished my first year of CS, so Im glad I had a chance to help.

Answer (score 0):

**The for Loop**:

> A for loop is a repetition control structure that allows you to
>   efficiently write a loop that needs to execute a specific number of
>   times.
>
> **A for loop is useful when you know how many times a task is to be
>   repeated.**

From the definition, you want to do the addition which the task 6 times. In better sense, in your case, the relation ship between for loop and addition process is the for loop do the addition the 6 times.

For better understanding read following

**Here is the flow of control in a for loop:**

**1**. The initialization step is executed first, and only once. This step allows you to declare and initialize any loop control variables. You are not required to put a statement here, as long as a semicolon appears.

**2**. Next, the Boolean expression is evaluated. If it is true, the body of the loop is executed. If it is false, the body of the loop does not execute and flow of control jumps to the next statement past the for loop.

**3**. After the body of the for loop executes, the flow of control jumps back up to the update statement. This statement allows you to update any loop control variables. This statement can be left blank, as long as a semicolon appears after the Boolean expression.

**4**. The Boolean expression is now evaluated again. If it is true, the loop executes and the process repeats itself (body of loop, then update step, then Boolean expression). After the Boolean expression is false, the for loop terminates.

**Note**: read `step 2` for your **better understanding**